# VLAN tagging and access port

Tags: vlan

What happens with a frame with 802.1Q tag (VLAN ID) that arrives on access port? It is a part of vlan hopping theory which I don't understand completly.

Comment: This answer can depend on the switch vendor/model/software version/configuration. As such, please consider editing as it could be considered too broad to answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an error, and the frame will be discarded. It may be an 'access' port from a service provider running 'provider bridging', then the frame will receive double tagging. It can get even more complex vlan translations. So it all depends on the full network setup.